# Compare two different hours using objectValue and return false if the different is 6 hours

Tags: c#

My class has a date register a property.

So, a create a another class that is a specification, where a validade some business rules.

Here's the attempt code:

```
 public class InfoPointingCannotBeSixOurLater : ISpecification<InfoPointing >
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(InfoPointing infopointing)
    {   
        return DateTime.Now.Hour - infopointing.Dateregister.Hour>=6;
    }
}
```

Rule:
The time that the infopointing was registered cannot be greater than 6 when compared to the current date.

The class is ok, my problem is how can i return false if that rule was not Satisfied

Any ideias how can i solve that?

Comment: First of all, your implementation will not work. If the current time is 1am of day 3 and the dateregister is 1pm of day 2, the difference by your method will be -12 and evaluate false even thought there is more than 6 hours. What you want is `return (DateTime.Now - infopointing.Dateregister).Hours>=6;` that way you get the correct time difference, considering the date, and getting the hour difference

Comment: Also, I didn't understood your question, aren't you already returning the bool?

Comment: @Magnetron I think your comment is actually the answer. The OP did not express it clearly, but he probably meant that his logic was failing and returning false negatives/positives.

Comment: @plalx yeah, it's not very clear. OP said that the class is ok, that's why I thought that the problem is another and he didn't tested yet for different dates to catch that error.

Comment: @Magnetron yes, its returning a bool, but i am having trouble doing the test. I am trying to find a logic to do this calculation of hours, but without success =(

Comment: @plalx Sorry If it was not clear. What I meant is that the class is returning the results, but it is returning the wrong calculation because the return the logic is wrong.

Comment: @Jhensen Then my comment is the answer

Comment: @Magnetron thx for the tips, will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `DateTime.Now.Hour` returns an integer disregarding the date. When `infopointing.Dateregister` is today, you have no problem, but when it is different dates, your logic breaks. What you need is to compute the difference between two dates and time and get the amount of hours that have elapsed. Try this:

```
return (DateTime.Now - infopointing.Dateregister).Hours>=6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public class InfoPointingCannotBeSixOurLater : ISpecification<InfoPointing >
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(InfoPointing infopointing)
    {   
        return DateTime.Now.Subtract(infopointing.Dateregister).TotalHours >=6;
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for the tips, will try. You and Magnetron post similar answers, but with different ways of doing

Comment: @Jhensen You're welcome, consider if there is more than 1 day difference between days, my solution returns e.g. 25 but the other one returns 1 (it means 1 day plus 1 hour)